# recovering vm data from crashed XenServer install

Tags: hard-drive, lvm, xenserver

We're using xenserver 5.6 from citrix to run our virtual machines. The box is old and creaky, and the hard drive went. (We had a super limited budget of $0 at the time). Turns out the only machine on there we actually needed, was the only one not backed up...

anyway, we've replace the hard drive, and reinstalled xensever. however while trying to find our old vm disk images, i have no idea where they sit, and i'm beginning to think they're on a lvm partition?

is there anyway to access the disk images from the old vm's on this hard disk, which is attached to the xenserver machine via a usb->sata converter?

Answer (score 1):

Is the disk containing the disk images intact ?

If you are able to see the disk Storage repository in xenserver. You should be able to reattach the SR by using:

```
xe sr-introduce
```

You should not by any means use the sr-create command since this will delete the old data.

Some more information would be helpful about your setup.